# Maven test resources are blank in target

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3

I am working on a Maven project that has some test resources; these are specified inside `<build>` with the following:

```
            <testResource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.csv</include>
                    <include>**/*.zip</include>
                    <include>**/*.xls</include>
                    <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
                    <include>**/*.jpg</include>
                    <include>**/*.pdf</include>
                </includes>
            </testResource>
```

When the tests are run all of the files that match these extensions are copied over form the `src/test/resources` into `/target/test-classes` to be used for the tests.

The problem is, the PDF files are copied over blank.  So, the file name is there; a valid PDF is in it's place, just completely blank.  There is no content, but it must have all of the necessary header information as it does open as a valid PDF file.

I can't understand where it is getting these blank files from.

### Example

- Original file -https://github.com/aembleton/files/blob/master/original.pdf
- Blank - https://github.com/aembleton/files/blob/master/blank.pdf

### What I've tried doing

- `mvn clean`
- Tried running tests on the command line and in IntelliJ
- Tried copying the files to other sub directories and to the top of `src/test/resources`.  The files are copied over into their new places, but still blank.
- Moved the PDFs to to `src/main/resources`.  The POM is set to include PDFs in this directory too for resources.  The PDFs are once again copied over blank, but to `target/classes`
- Rebooted

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 with 5.4.0-31 kernel
- Ext4 file system
- OpenJDK 1.8.0_252
- Apache Maven 3.6.3

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: It's the filtering. Somewhere in the PDF, but after the header, are the placeholder signs. So Maven will replace them with an empty string as the placeholder key will be unknown. Try it with deactivated filtering und you'll see, the PDF is copied as whole file.

Comment: If you are filtering binary content like zip, pdf, jpeg etc. it's very likely to break the content. So I strongly discourage to filter any kind of binary content.

Comment: Thank you @SvenDöring.  I've updated my POM and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
<testResource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>
        <include>**/*.xml</include>
        <include>**/*.csv</include>
    </includes>
</testResource>
<testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.pdf</include>
        <include>**/*.jpg</include>
        <include>**/*.zip</include>
        <include>**/*.xls</include>
        <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
    </includes>
</testResource>
```

**Explanation:**

Filtering maybe be corrupting the PDF.
Filtering works by replacing specific string tokens with other values. 
The solution would be to exclude the filtering from the PDF.

Comment: Filtering of jpg, xls, etc. will likely fail.

Comment: Updated answer to include all files that could potentially cause a filtering problem